# Posting Questions - "allow new options", "allow multiple votes"?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Playing with the Facebook Questions Graph API (wasn't clear from the API documentation) I've noticed that it's possible to specify whether "friends can add options" (by means of an `allow_new_options` field). Setting this field to `true` has the additional effect that "friends *can* vote multiple options". Setting it to `false` has the effect that "friends *cannot* vote multiple options". The two things ("allow new options" and "allow multiple votes") however, in my opinion, are and should be unrelated. Does anyone know whether *or not* it's possible to specify separately that "friends can add options" and "friends can vote multiple options"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be aware that Facebook is discontinuing it's Questions product altogether. Any app you build right now will be obsolete in a few days.

http://techcrunch.com/2012/10/19/facebook-questions-shut-down/

http://www.businessinsider.com/quora-wins-facebook-is-shutting-down-its-questions-product-2012-10

Comment: Looks like it's still going to be used in Groups and Pages so the Questions API should (??) still be available...

Comment: I'm not sure. I just wanted to warn you so you don't end up wasting your time. Do more research on this before you start.